# $_POST and $_GET not working on var_dump but working on loggued requests

Tags: php, post, var-dump

I have a very simple form like I've done dozens, but this one isn't working for a reason that eludes me.
When var_dumping the $_POST variable after submit it's empty but it's working on the request_maker from chrome.
here is where it is submited:

```
echo "  <form method='POST'>
            <input type='button' class='button' style='height:50px' name='manage' value='export' onclick='submit()'/>
            </form>";
    var_dump($_POST);
```

the var_dump returns an empty array.

From other subjects I've seen they talk about php.ini wich was unchanged since a long time on my side, no updates were made, and others post requests on different pages are working

Comment: Get rid of the onclick parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not POSTing the form when you press the button. You are performing the `onclick` event.

Remove the `onclick` attribute (or make sure that the submit() function is POSTing).

Comment: Yes the problem was the onClick event so I changed my code to the following:
<input type='hidden' name='manage' value='export'/>
    <input type='submit' value='submit'/>

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump($_POST)
```

Only works when you submit form. so change code as mention below you will able to dump data

```
if(isset($_POST)){
   var_dump($_POST);
}
```

also put action  in form Tag

```
action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
```

Other Thing try put Input field to get clear idea

```
 <input type="text" name="name"><br>
```

Comment: He says it is empty after the submit.